# Как скопировать выделенную строку одного DataGridView одной формы в другой DataGridView другой формы?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, c#-8.0

Существует основная таблица, которая должна формировать список:
[image: Основная форма]

При нажатии кнопки "Выбрать из типовых" открывается заполненная таблица.

[image: Форма с типовыми объектами]

Как обратиться из дочерней формы к родительской, что бы при двойном клике по строке, выбранная строка копировалась в основную таблицу?

[image: Диалог подтверждения копирования]

Код первой формы:

```
    namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void opensziform_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SZIForm sziForm = new SZIForm(this);
            sziForm.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Код второй формы:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class SZIForm : Form
    {
        public SZIForm(Form1 ParrentForm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        private void SZIForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        private void dataGridTypeSZI_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = dataGridTypeSZI.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
            dataGridTypeSZI.Rows[index].Selected = true;
            DialogResult dialogres = MessageBox.Show("Копирнуть??",
                                    "Подтверждение",
                                    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                    MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
                                    MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            if (dialogres == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                //Скопировать выбранную строку в основную таблицу
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: В конструкторе второй формы вы получаете ссылку на родительскую: `SZIForm(Form1 ParrentForm)`. Сохраните её в поле и далее через неё получайте доступ. / Вместо ссылки на форму можно передавать ссылку на датагрид или источник данных...

Comment: А как вы заполняете данными DGV? Лучше всего использовать в качестве источника данных `BindingSource` у него есть свойство `Current` и тогда легко скопировать `Current` из одного `BindingSource` в другой.

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут толпа способов передачи данных между формами: http://www.cyberforum.ru/windows-forms/thread110436.html

Можно передать ссылку на родителя в конструкторе(что вы кстати делаете, но не пользуетесь: public SZIForm(Form1 ParrentForm)), можно передать ссылку на родительский датагрид(сделав его пабликом), можно воспользоваться owner, в конце концов можно даже из родительской формы подписаться на событие двойного клика по дочернему датагриду(только не забыть отписаться если дочерняя закрывается).

Но лучше я(ибо всё и начинается с "как мне изменить текстбокс с другой формы", а потом...), расскажу страшный секретный способ(которого там вроде нет) для любой передачи чего угодно между чем угодно, куда угодно и откуда угодно :D. Создать (там откуда надо что-либо получать) своё событие, например:

```
    public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
//аргументы для передачи
        public object Value { get; set; }
        public Exception Ex { get; set; }
        public MyEventArgs(object value, Exception ex) { Value = value; Ex = ex; }
    }
    public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e);
    public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
    private void myEvent(MyEventArgs e) { MyEvent?.Invoke(this, e); }

И потом, когда захотим, оповестить всех желающих, вызвать из метода: 

myEvent(new MyEventArgs("тут что-нибудь", null));
```

Добавлять/убирать желающих(внутри этих желающих) примерно так:

```
[ссылка на генератора события].MyEvent += [обработчик события];
[ссылка на генератора события].MyEvent -= [обработчик события];
```

Убирать событие перед уничтожением отслеживаемого объекта обязательно. Естественно нужно знать ссылку того объекта, на который мы хотим подписаться (для нестатических она берется в момент "= new "). Если ещё и потоки разные, то желающий будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myClass.MyEvent += eventHandler;
        }

        private delegate void MyDelegate(MyClass.MyEventArgs e);
        private void eventHandler(object sender, MyClass.MyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e != null) { if (InvokeRequired) { Invoke(new MyDelegate(currentEventHandler), e); } else { currentEventHandler(e); } }
        }
        private void currentEventHandler(MyClass.MyEventArgs e)
        {
            // тут делай что хочешь
            if (e.Ex != null) MessageBox.Show(e.Ex.Message); return;
            string str = (string)e.Value;
        }
    }
```